# slick slider растягивает слайд

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

подскажите, почему в каталоге в товаре slick slider срабатывает так криво, то есть первому слайду задает ширину в 4000

[Здесь](http://litesite.extremje.beget.tech/katalog)

вызываю так

```
$(".slider_img_item").slick({
    autoplay: false,
    dots: false,
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1

});
```

Comment: Добавьте ваш `html` код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в использовании фракций `fr` в грид контейнере.
Используйте другой способ для указания ширины колонки, например `repeat(4, calc((100% - 75px) / 4))`

Comment: а почему fr так влияет? ведь она на контейнер, а слайдер в каждом из item

Comment: Точно не знаю, может он не понимает саму ед. измерения `fr`.

Comment: спасибо вам за подсказку